# Calling cudaDeviceSynchronize() only for a particular kernel

Tags: asynchronous, cuda, gpgpu

I call kernels `KerA` and `KerB` asynchronously. Kernel `KerC` is dependent on `KerB` finishing but independent of `KerA`. So how to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in such a way that means **`KerC` waits for `KerB` to finish but not `KerA`**?

```
Time -------------------------->
| KerA ------------------------>
| KerB ------> | KerC --------->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this with CUDA streams.

If you do not use any stream, the default stream (aka stream '0') is used, and you get no concurrency (as if `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is inserted before and after every CUDA operation, cf. [these slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf)).

However, if `KerA` runs in stream 0, `KerB` and `KerC` run in stream 1, you will get what you want, i.e. synchronous calls between `KerB` and `KerC`, which are asynchronous w.r.t. `KerA`. You can use `cudaStreamSynchronize(streamid)` to synchronize w.r.t. a specific stream.

```
Time ------------------------------------>
| Stream 0: KerA ------------------------>
| Stream 1: KerB ------> | KerC --------->
```

Examples are available in the [slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf) I linked. You can also check the [`simpleStreams`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simplestreams) or [`concurrentKernels`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels) samples of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I've not used pinned memory before, so please could you also clarify the requirement of using "`cudaMemcpyAsync` with host from 'pinned' memory". I am currently uploading 100MB+ of data to device without streams at the start of my code using Thrust - if I use streams later in my code, will each stream still have read access to this data? How much pinned memory can I use - over 100MB? Will streams not work without pinned memory?

Comment: Also, can streams further split into sub-streams?

Comment: You need to worry about pinned memory and [`cudaMallocHost`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad) if you want to do some asynchronous memcpy. Yes, each stream has access to global memory, but you need to be sure that different streams will not create RAW/WAW hazards ("Data used by concurrent operations should be independent"). And no, there is no such thing as sub-streams as far as I know (unless we are talking about the latest Dynamic-parallelism-enabled GPUs I suppose).